# Best way to create number-index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So I've been thinking of different  solutions for creating a pandas index where the number corresponds to the row number. I think I'm either overthinking it or missing some god simple solution. I've spent way to many hours thinking of this.

As of now I'm doing it with a for loop running through df.iterrows(), adding each iteration into a list, then adding the list to pandas, then making that the index.

What I have:

```
apple 5 3
banana 3  2
pear 4  5
```

what I want:

```
1 Apple 5 3 
2 Banana 3 2
3 Pear 4 5
```

Comment: `df=df.reset_index()`? or if you want that your index starts with 1 then use `df.index=df.reset_index().index+1`

Comment: would be better to ditch the `iterrows` approach all together, can you show your starting data and the code your employing?

Comment: df.index=df.reset_index().index+1 was exactly what I was looking for. Have totally missed it's possible to use "+1".

Comment: Why not `RangeIndex: `df.set_index(pd.RangeIndex(1, len(df)+1))`